# How to create new google spread sheet and open it with Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

im new  to this and have been looking every where how to do this:

1. Create new Google Spread Sheet.
2. Open new Google Spread Sheet.
3. Add code to new Google Spread Sheet.

Ive seen this code, but dont really understand it much. Can somebody explain or help me with this task?

```
var files = DriveApp.searchFiles(
'starred = true and mimeType = "' + MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS + '"');
while (files.hasNext()) {
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.open(files.next());
var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheets()[0];
Logger.log(sheet.getName());
```

Comment: What code is about `Add code to new Google Spread Sheet.`?

Answer (score 0):

Would duplicating a blank spreadsheet that already has App Script code attached to it work in your situation?

**Steps Needed:**

1. Create a blank Spreadsheet.
2. Add your code to the blank Spreadsheet.
3. Use the following code to make a copy of the blank spreadsheet. The App Script file will also be on the newly copied file.

**To make a copy of the blank Spreadsheet, use this:**

```
function copySpreadsheet() {
  var templateSpreadsheetID = [Enter the Spreadsheet ID]
  var newSheetName = [Enter the name you want the copied Spreadsheet to be]
  var newSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(templateSpreadsheetID).copy(newSheetName)
  console.log(newSheet.getUrl())
}
```

**Notes:**

- You'll need to replace `[Enter the Spreadsheet ID]` with the Spreadsheet ID from the blank sheet you created in Step 1
- You'll need to replace `[Enter the name you want the copied Spreadsheet to be]` with what ever name the new copied spreadsheet should be. It's optional, so you could remove it.
- If you'd like to do further actions to the spreadsheet after it has been duplicated, you can use the `newSheet` variable to run your [sheet actions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet)

***Can somebody explain or help me with this task?***

The code you shared is a script that extract the first sheet name of each starred Spreadsheet.

```
//Returns all the starred files that are a Google Sheet file type:
var files = DriveApp.searchFiles('starred = true and mimeType = "' + MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS + '"');

//Loops through all of the files that were returned:
while (files.hasNext()) {
  
  //Opens the current sheet from the loop
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.open(files.next());

  //Returns the first sheet from the spreadsheet (position 0)
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheets()[0];
  
  //Logs the sheet name
  Logger.log(sheet.getName());
}
```

Comment: Francisco, did that help?